# On click slider next and previous button i get $curr[action] is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am following this Js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ryt3nu1v/10/

My Result:

[image: My Output]

I am making a slider that display age as I have an array that following ages

15,25,35,45,55

I am trying to display them in slider
expected behavior is to see the next age when i click on next button

Code that I used from fiddle according to my need is

```
          //Age slider
          $('div.result-age:gt(0)').hide(); //Hide all but the first one

var $allSlides = $('div.result-age'), 
    traverseDefault = "first", //set the defaults
    actionDefault ="arrow-next";

$('.arrow-next,.selected-arrow-left-pointer').click(function(){

    var traverse = traverseDefault,
        action = actionDefault;

    if($(this).is('.selected-arrow-left-pointer')){ //if action is prev
        traverse = "last"; //set traverse to last in case nothing is available
        action = "selected-arrow-left-pointer"; //set action to prev
    }

    var $curr = $allSlides.filter(':visible'), //get the visible slide
        $nxtTarget =  $curr[action](".result-age"); //get the next target based on the action.

    $curr.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000).hide(); //hide current one

    if (!$nxtTarget.length){ //if no next
        $nxtTarget = $allSlides[traverse](); //based on traverse pick the next one
    }

    $nxtTarget.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000); //show the target

});
          //age slider end
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div class="result-box">
<div class="selected-arrow-left-pointer"></div>
<div class="result-age"><span><h4 v-for="(row,key,index) in ages">ALL ages here currently being display all at once</h4></span></div>
<div class="arrow-next"></div>

</div>
```

My current style is that age will be displayed in center with left and right sides having next and previous button

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you make your code runnable ?

Comment: runnable as in?
If you are asking whether it is even functional or not, then it and i am editing the question to show picture

Comment: What I can see is that, in the jsfiddle you have attached on the top of the question, all the slides are predefined, so the next item is easily fetchable, but in your code, the data are not predefined. I mean only one slide is there, that could be the problem

Comment: add ```overflow:hidden``` css property and then let me know if it works

Comment: Uzair its not working 
And Abin Thaha yes my data is not predefined as i am getting values from array

Comment: ok can you add runnable code snippet in the question because I tried running your code in jsfiddle its not displaying the slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v-for` is creating mutliple `h4` tag but you need create `result` div for each numbers so move your `v-for` inside your div tag .Then , you are using wrong values for `actionDefault` and `action` it should be `next` & `prev` where next refer to next slide and prev refer to previous slide not the classnames .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('div.result-age:gt(0)').hide();
var $allSlides = $('div.result-age'),
  traverseDefault = "first",
  actionDefault = "next"; //use next ..refer next node

$('.arrow-next,.selected-arrow-left-pointer').click(function() {
  var traverse = traverseDefault,
    action = actionDefault;
  if ($(this).is('.selected-arrow-left-pointer')) {
    traverse = "last";
    action = "prev"; //use prev..refer prev..
  }

  var $curr = $allSlides.filter(':visible');
  $nxtTarget = $curr[action](".result-age");

  $curr.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000).hide();
  if (!$nxtTarget.length) {
    $nxtTarget = $allSlides[traverse]();
  }

  $nxtTarget.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
span.next,
span.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result-box">
  <div class="selected-arrow-left-pointer">
    << </div>
      <!--your div should have ` v-for="(row,key,index) in ages"`-->
      <div class="result-age"><span><h4>1</h4></span></div>
      <div class="result-age"><span><h4>2</h4></span></div>
      <div class="result-age"><span><h4>3</h4></span></div>
      <div class="arrow-next"> >> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you swati but i have tried  loopin result-age div and the result is in column form as in my picture output that I gave in question

Comment: See html generated code if the divs are repeated . Also , put your entire code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //all code inside ... })`

Comment: I changed div class from h4's class to div in which it was inside and now it is working.
Thank you

Comment: Glad i was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, you were using `arrow-next` instead of `next`, and `selected-arrow-left-pointer` instead of `prev`.  Check the below working snippet. The data can be provided dynamically as you wish, currently I have given static data.

The `next` and `prev` are reserved keywords and hence the `$curr[action]` was expecting a function in return, while in your case it was `$curr['arrow-next'] instead of $curr['next'], which was returning undefined, and hence the error occurred.

```js
//Age slider
      $("div.result-age:gt(0)").hide(); //Hide all but the first one

      var $allSlides = $("div.result-age"),
        traverseDefault = "first", //set the defaults
        actionDefault = "next";

      $(".next,.prev").click(function () {
        var traverse = traverseDefault,
          action = actionDefault;

        if ($(this).is(".prev")) {
          //if action is prev
          traverse = "last"; //set traverse to last in case nothing is available
          action = "prev"; //set action to prev
        }
        var currentData = $allSlides.filter(":visible"), //get the visible slide
          $nxtTarget = currentData[action](".result-age"); //get the next target based on the action.

        currentData.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000).hide(); //hide current one

        if (!$nxtTarget.length) {
          //if no next
          $nxtTarget = $allSlides[traverse](); //based on traverse pick the next one
        }

        $nxtTarget.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000); //show the target
      });
```

```css
.next, .prev {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result-box">
      <div class="prev"><</div>
      <div class="result-age">
        <span><h4>ALL ages here currently being display all at once</h4></span>
      </div>
      <div class="result-age">
        <span><h4>2</h4></span>
      </div>
      <div class="result-age">
        <span><h4>3</h4></span>
      </div>
      <div class="result-age">
        <span><h4>4</h4></span>
      </div>
      <div class="result-age">
        <span><h4>5</h4></span>
      </div>
      <div class="next">></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abin that solved my error but i am still getting the display as in my picture

Comment: You mean the css ?

Comment: Currently the numbers are not being displayed as per the image, instead, only one slide will be active at a time. If that is what you are trying to achieve, you need to update styles using css

Comment: With the code you are trying it is not possible to achieve it. As per the current JS code provided, only one item will be visible in the UI at a time. You will require another js code to have a functionality as per the image, also you will require to do some css stylings as well.

Comment: Thank you it solved my error and i placed class of parent div in jquery code